# Aquaporin and the exclusion of $H^+$

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane, membrane-transport

As I read in my textbook, aquaporins exclude $H^+$ when absorbing water, but where does this $H^+$ come from? Additionally, is $H_3O^+$ a liquid that looks like regular water?

Comment: $\ce{H_3O^+}$ is just representation of acidic water. You'd get much better answers about this on chemistry.SE

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where the $H^+$ comes from in the context of this information. The textbook is just saying that the aquaporin is permeable to $H_2O$ but not to $H_3O^+$ (nor, presumably, to $OH^-$).

In any aqueous solution, especially in the presence of acids, some of the molecules will be $H_3O^+$. The pH tells you how many. It doesn't really make sense to think about what a solution of $H_3O^+$ would look like.